# Extend period of WaitHandle.WaitOne timeout

Tags: .net, multithreading

Is there an *existing type* in the framework which will allow me to do something similar to the example below? Basically, I'd like the ability to increase the duration of the timeout.

```
MagicWaitHandle waitHandle;

Main()
{
 var fooBar = new FooBar();
 fooBar.OnEvent += HandleEvent;
 fooBar.Start(); // starts new thread

 waitHandle.WaitOne(new TimeSpan(0,1,0)); // suspend
}

HandleEvent(Foo f)
{
 if(f.SomeCondition) waitHandle.ExtendWaitPeriodBy(new TimeSpan(0,1,0)); // extend
 else if(f.OtherCondition) waitHandle.Set(); // signal
}
```

Comment: What does it mean by `waitHandle.ExtendWaitPeriodBy` ? What it is supposed to do?

Comment: It extends the WaitOne timeout. i.e. If `WaitOne` was initially called with a timeout of 1 minute, and `ExtendWaitPeriodBy` was called (with a value of 1 minute), 30 seconds after calling `WaitOne`, the amount of time remaining before WaitOne times out would be 90 sec, not 30 sec.

Comment: Ok, what if `WaitOne` returned, and called again? Does the extension count here also? or it should be applied for only for threads which is already waiting with timeout?

Comment: Only waiting threads.

Comment: There is nothing like that exist. You can override `WaitHandle.WaitOne` and add your extension logic there. Of you can simply check return value of `WaitOne`; if it is false, apply extension time if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in framework which offers what you're asking for. Nevertheless you could write a decorator for `WaitHandle` and use it instead.

Following pseudo code can help you to start your implementation.

```
public class MagicWaitHandle : WaitHandle
{
    private readonly WaitHandle inner;
    public MagicWaitHandle(WaitHandle inner)
    {
        if (inner == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("inner");
        this.inner = inner;
        this.SafeWaitHandle = inner.SafeWaitHandle;
    }

    public override bool WaitOne(TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        if (!base.WaitOne(timeout) )
        {
            if (<needs Apply Extended Timeout>)
            {
                return base.WaitOne(extendedTimeSpan);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override bool WaitOne(TimeSpan timeout, bool exitContext)
    {
        if (!base.WaitOne(timeout, exitContext))
        { 
            if (<needs Apply Extended Timeout>)
            {
                return base.WaitOne(extendedTimeSpan, exitContext);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void ExtendWaitPeriodBy(TimeSpan timeSpan)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Make sure you consider thread safety while implementing. Once you finish implementing your `MagicWaitHandle`, you can use it as

```
MagicWaitHandle magicHandle = new MagicWaitHandle(new ManualResetEvent(false));
...
magicHandle.WaitOne(timeout);
```

Else where in code

```
magicHandle.ExtendWaitPeriodBy(extensionTimeout);
```